# GCP Service Account permissions to access Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

Could someone explain to me what permissions I need to set on 'service account' in GCP so this account can access Firebase database with read/write access ?

I read a lot of documentation and still it doesn't not work in my Google Function app with error: `rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = Missing or insufficient permissions.`

Comment: Firebase Real time database or Firestore?

Comment: Ooopss.. sorry - my mistake - I found an answer: the machine where the application was running was not logged in with Service Account and actually use different credentials to login - so because of this is was denied. Once I re-login with service account credentials - it start working as expected. Nothing need to be done on Firestore side

Answer (score 1):

Posting as a community wiki based on the comment of @AlexF:

> I found an answer: the machine where the application was running was not logged in with Service Account and actually used different credentials to login - so because of this it was denied. Once I re-login with service account credentials - it starts working as expected. Nothing needs to be done on Firestore side.